# How to control another program in your own java written program?

Tags: java, eclipse, controls, save

I wanted to ask you somewhat simple question in Java lang using Eclipse, as I learned C# language about 2 years, about a couple days I started directly learning this language (Java), now all I am doing is writing a simple programs, like the one I am working on at this minute, it's like a master password program that takes your ID and password for facebook and gmail and hotmail , and then promopts you to type your own short simple name and password which will save your time and make it easier for you to log into any log-in required site, therefore avoiding the Key-loggers (Spyware)....
I wrote my program that runs another program like Messenger, I'm now almost done, all I need how can I give commands or pass String variables to the textboxes in the windows of the msn messenger program, this is the line I tried to pass variables like the input ID goes to the Username textbox in the messenger, and also the same for pass input...

**Things I wish You tell me also: how do i make a saved file that will not repeat the first inputs like your original password, i mean that the next use will take you just to type your ID and master pass, and also how do i control the programs with more than pasting a strings.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.awt.Robot` to find the MSN Messenger window and type into.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your respond, but why when i type the following: Import java.awt.Robot; it says its never used, how can i do what you mean?

Comment: I've looked at your recent activity on StackOverflow and seems what you are really really focused on MSN Messenger. If you want to make a bot for MSN Messenger, there is a Java API for that. See here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml  ... they even have an example of logging in: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml/wiki/BasicMessenger.java